# How to extract certain information from an outlook 2007 email and send it to an excel workbook

Tags: vba

Every day I get over 50 orders in Outlook 2007. They all come in a standard form, and I would like to be able to extract certain items to be sent to an existing excel workbook for reporting. Below is a sample of an order form. Can anyone help me with a Macro to automatically extract this information. The Items all arrive into their own folder currently, and as it is now, I manually go through these orders and enter them into our ordering system, and then I have to go back and transfer the information into a spreadsheet for reporting purposes. Some clients want different information on their report, but if I had an example I can tailor the code to choose the information I need for each report. Thank you so much for any help with this.

Require Date:
Contact info:
Client_Id:
Vehicle_No:
Move Type:
Move Require:
Price Quote:
Temp Tag:
Weight Slip:

YEAR:
MAKE:
MODEL:
VIN:
CLIENT_NAME:
GVW: 
COLOR:
PLATE STATE:

EN_ROUTE:
FROM_STORAGE:
FULL_DETAILING:
CONTROL_NO:

FROM_NAME:
FROM_ADDR_1:
FROM_ADDR_2:
FROM_ADDR_3:
FROM_CITY:
FROM_STATE:
FROM_ZIP:
FROM_PHONE:
FROM_PHONE2:
FROM_PHONE_EXT:
FROM_PHONE2_EXT:
FROM_EMAIL:

TO_NAME:
TO_ADDR_1:
TO_ADDR_2:
TO_ADDR_3:
TO_CITY:
TO_STATE:
TO_ZIP:
TO_PHONE:
TO_PHONE2:
TO_PHONE_EXT:
TO_PHONE2_EXT:
TO_EMAIL:

Answer (score 0):

If you have to put these data manually into ordering system anyway, maybe it would be easier to extract data from there for reporting purposes.